# Performance test of CSS frameworks

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, performance-testing

I'm planning to conduct performance test of various responsive CSS frameworks. I will be developing test web pages all of the same layout using different frameworks (eg. Bootstrap, Foundation etc.). How do i conduct performance tests on these test pages analyzing the responsiveness of these frameworks ? Is there any tools available ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Performance can be tested in multiple ways.
- It can be done using the audit options and performance options that comes with Chrome.
- Performance checking plugin also exists [plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/performance-analyser/djgfmlohefpomchfabngccpbaflcahjf?hl=en)
- Below are few [tools](https://techbeacon.com/web-performance-testing-top-12-free-open-source-tools-consider)

**Siege** – This http load-testing and benchmarking utility was designed to let web developers measure code under duress, to see how it will stand up to load on the Internet. Siege supports basic authentication, cookies, and HTTP and HTTPS protocols, and lets the user hit a web server with a configurable number of simulated web browsers. Those browsers place the server “under siege.”

**Apache Bench** – Use this tool for benchmarking your Apache HTTP server, to get an idea of how Apache performs.

**Httperf** – This tool measures web server performance and provides a flexible facility for generating varied HTTP workloads and measuring server performance. The focus is not on implementing a particular benchmark but on providing a robust, high-performance tool that facilitates the construction of both micro- and macro-level benchmarks. The three distinguishing characteristics of httperf are its robustness, which includes the ability to generate and sustain server overload; support for the HTTP/1.1 and SSL protocols; and its extensibility to new workload generators and performance measurements.